# How to run tasks in parallel in dagster?

Tags: python, dagster

I am using dagster to running into local node.js microservices pipelines, in order to execute test.

The ide is execute n docker_files, and n node.js microservices, easily like you can do with dagster.

The problem is that when I execute the first second one task a shell command to execute a docker container, dagsteer keep in that point, and not execute all task in the same level.

Current dag logs like this

```
login aws
    |
    |
    |
    v
[docker_elastic, docker_kafka, sleep_10]
                                  |
                                  |
                                  |
                                  v
[node_service_one, node_service_two, node_service__three]
```

Can I execute at same time all docker_elastic and all node_services?

Is there another easy to configure option to build a local dags easily?

Thanks

Comment: There is a similar question with answers https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66601150/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using the new job/op APIs, then Dagster will by default use a multiprocess executor, which will be able to run multiple tasks in parallel.

If you're using the pipeline/solid APIs, then you can pass in run configuration to tell Dagster to use the multiprocess executor instead of the default single process executor. If you're launching a pipeline from Dagit, you'd pass in run config that looked like:

```
execution:
    multiprocess: {}
```

If you're launching these runs from the python apis, then the run config would be:

`run_config={"execution": {"multiprocess": {}}}`

Note that you'll need to use a multiprocess-compatible IOManager, such as the fs_io_manager (`from dagster import fs_io_manager`).

Full docs on multiprocess execution are here: https://docs.dagster.io/0.12.14/concepts/solids-pipelines/pipeline-execution#multiprocessing-execution

Comment: Edit: As of Dagster 0.13.0, the multiprocess executor is now the default for any new job, so you will not need to modify this using the run config.